# How to find attribute name with the highest value from a Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I have those attributes with number type in a DE and want to get the attribute name with the highest value from a record. This following code is what I'm trying to do that purpose, the code didn't get error but it didn't "print" anything. I wonder if I did something wrong.

I put the code on a Cloudpage:

```
%%[
    Var @Foodie, @Culture_Shapers, @Family_minded, @Collectors, @Wellness_seekers
    Set @Foodie = Lookup('MyDE test1', 'Foodie', 'CustomerID', 'No1230987654')
    Set @Culture_Shapers = Lookup('MyDE test1', 'Culture Shapers', 'CustomerID', 'No1230987654')
    Set @Family_minded = Lookup('MyDE test1', 'Family Minded', 'CustomerID', 'No1230987654')
    Set @Collectors = Lookup('MyDE test1', 'Collectors', 'CustomerID', 'No1230987654')
    Set @Wellness_seekers = Lookup('MyDE test1', 'Wellness Seekers', 'CustomerID', 'No1230987654')
]%%
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
  // Get values from AMPscript variables
  var Foodie = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@Foodie');
  var Culture_Shapers = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@Culture_Shapers');
  var Family_minded = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@Family_minded');
  var Collectors = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@Collectors');
  var Wellness_seekers = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@Wellness_seekers');
 
  // Add them to a dictionary as keys and value
  var dict = {};
  dict['Foodie'] = Foodie;
  dict['Culture Shapers'] = Culture_Shapers;
  dict['Family minded'] = Family_minded;
  dict['Collectors'] = Collectors;
  dict['Wellness seekers'] = Wellness_seekers;
  
  // Function to get the key with the highest value
  const getMax = object => {
     return Object.keys(object).filter(x => {
        return object[x] == Math.max.apply(null, 
        Object.values(object));
       });
    };

  var results = getMax(dict); // return array
  Platform.Response.Write(results[0]); // print to the cloudpage
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED BASED ON COMMENT**  Adding in way to retain name and value along with order based on value

---

What I would do is push the values into an array and then do **array.sort** to sort it in a DESC order. You can then just grab the first value and that is the highest value.

example of array.sort:

```js
 var array = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

 array.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x < y) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (x > y) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
 });
//Output: [1,5,10,25,40,100]
```

To do DESC, you would do:

```js
 var array = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

 array.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x < y) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (x > y) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
 });
//Output: [100,40,25,10,5,1]
```

So final code would be:

```js
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
  
  var array = []

  //LookupRows to only pull once
  var rows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('MyDE test1','CustomerID','No1230987654');

  // Get values from returned rowset
  var Foodie = rows[0]["Foodie"];
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = "Foodie"
  obj.value = Foodie
  array.push(obj)

  var Culture_Shapers = rows[0]["Culture_Shapers"]
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = "Culture_Shapers"
  obj.value = Culture_Shapers
  array.push(obj)

  var Family_minded = rows[0]["Family_minded"];
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = "Family_minded"
  obj.value = Family_minded
  array.push(obj)

  var Collectors = rows[0]["Collectors"];
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = "Collectors"
  obj.value = Collectors
  array.push(obj)

  var Wellness_seekers = rows[0]["Wellness_seekers"];
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = "Wellness_seekers"
  obj.value = Wellness_seekers
  array.push(obj)

  
  array.sort(function(x, y) {
    if (x.value < y.value) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (x.value > y.value) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
 });


  var results = array; // return array
  Platform.Response.Write(Platform.Function.Stringify(results)); // print to the cloudpage
  
</script>
```

Which would result in:

```js
//Given:
  //Foodie = 100
  //Culture_Shapers = 200
  //Family_minded = 5
  //Collectors = 27
  //Wellness_seekers = 55

//Output:
  [{name:"Culture_Shapers",value:200},{name:"Foodie",value:100},{name:Wellness_seekers",value:55},{name:"Collectors",value:27},{name:"Family_minded",value:5}]
```

so you could do:

```js
  Write(results[0].name + ' is the largest number, which is: ' + results[0].value)
  //Which would output: 'Culture_Shapers is the largest number, which is 200'
```

From there you have an ordered array of objects containing Name/Value matches of your data that you can use in whatever way you need.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington it's really a nice idea, however I think there was a misunderstanding. I want to get the Attribute name not its value. It seems the code above will get the highest value but not the Attribute name which contained the highest value. Moreover, it may have multiple attributes with the same values. E.g. Foodie and Collecters have the same highest value so the result supposes to have those attribute names

Comment: you can match the values back from the resulting array. I will update my answer to show this

Comment: @duyduc27 - Actually edited to include name/value as objects in the array for easier future reference rather than the extra processing for a match back.

Comment: I tried to use the code but my cloudpage showed nothing but a 500 internal error. I noticed that the code wouldn't show any error (loading icon) in preview mode if I removed the function. It's weird because I feel like the cloudpage didn't allow we put any function inside it?

Comment: @duyduc27 - apologies, I had a typo in the script and put the `.value` part in the wrong spots.  This version should now work as expected.

Comment: It works like a charm! The idea which adding everything to an array and sort it in a DESC order was really good! , it can solve many things without making it complicated. Thank you so much. By the way, can I use it in automation studio? Like I create a script activity with the code and then use an automation to update all rows in the DE based on attribute with highest value?

Comment: @duyduc27 - you can use this in automation studio, but it would be difficult to transfer this order into a DE. You would likely need a second DE to target for the order of data to be updated in this way. Another option is to try preprocessing it via SQL but on existing data it may have the same requirements.